# get or default nested column with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

With Apache Spark (v2), I have the following schema:

```
root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)
```

I am running query like this:

```
SELECT foo.toto, foo.bar FROM data
```

Since "foot" have no field "toto", it fails with an Exception. How can I use a default value instead?

I wrote a UDF (but I am sure this thing already exist...):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

spark.udf.register("map_get", (root:GenericRowWithSchema, path: String) => {

    var fields = path.split("\\.")
    var buffer:Row = root
    val lastItem = fields.last

    fields = fields.dropRight(1)

    fields.foreach( (field:String) => {
        if (buffer != null) {
            if (buffer.schema.fieldNames.contains(field)) {
                buffer = buffer.getStruct(buffer.fieldIndex(field))
            } else {
                buffer = null
            }
        }
    })

    if (buffer == null) {
        ""
    } else {
        buffer.getString(buffer.fieldIndex(lastItem))
    }
})
```

```
SELECT map_get(foo, "toto") FROM data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an alternative. First lets create some data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

case class Foo(bar: String, baz: String)
case class Record(foo: Foo)

val df = Seq(
  Record(Foo("bar1", "baz1")),
  Record(Foo("bar2", "baz2")))
.toDF()

// +------------+
// |         foo|
// +------------+
// |[bar1, baz1]|
// |[bar2, baz2]|
// +------------+
```

Then we use StructType and reflection to retrieve the schema:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
val fooSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Record].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

var cols = fooSchema.flatMap(st => st.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].map(sf => s"${st.name}.${sf.name}"))
//cols: Seq[String] = List(foo.bar, foo.baz)

def map_get(cname: String, cols: Seq[String], default: String = "") : Column = if(cols.contains(cname)) col(cname) else lit(default)
```

`cols` will contain all possible columns `foo.bar, foo.baz` in our case. `map_get` search for `cname` in the given `cols` list, if the search was successful returns a valid column `col(cname)` otherwise `lit(default)`. The results of the `map_get` will be used in the select as shown in the examples.

```scala
//valid call
df.select(
  map_get("foo.bar", cols)
).show
// +----+
// | bar|
// +----+
// |bar1|
// |bar2|
// +----+

//invalid column with default value == "test"
df.select(
  map_get("foo.bar1", cols, "test")
).show
// +----+
// |test|
// +----+
// |test|
// |test|
// +----+

df.select(
  map_get("foo.bar", cols, ""), //valid with empty default
  map_get("foo.baz", cols, ""), //valid with empty default
  map_get("foo.baa", cols, "")  //invalid with empty default
).show

// +----+----+---+
// | bar| baz|   |
// +----+----+---+
// |bar1|baz1|   |
// |bar2|baz2|   |
// +----+----+---+
```

Comment: Much better indeed! Does it work as UDF and pure Spark SQL?

Comment: I tried to avoid an UDF func for better performance but an UDF it is definitely possible with a couple of changes though